# How to separate row *and* column caption from table content with a little portion of white space?

Tags: tables, columns, white-space, hhline

I actually thought that this question has already been asked but I could not find anything similar to it. I would like to separate the row and column caption from the table content in the following way:

```
          +-------+-------+
          |       |       |
          | Col 1 | Col 2 |
          |       |       |
          +-------+-------+
+-------+ +-------+-------+
|       | |       |       |
| Row 1 | |   1   |   2   |
|       | |       |       |
+-------+ +-------+-------+
|       | |       |       |
| Row 2 | |   3   |   4   |
|       | |       |       |
+-------+ +-------+-------+
```

Note that the space between the row caption and the table content has just been inserted for aesthetical reasons and to make clear what I mean.

I already tried using something like the `hhline` package and experimented with it a bit, but I never came up with a result like this.

---

**Edit:** I have created an example with Libre Office in order to show what I mean.

[image]

Comment: So do you want white space there or not (asking for both the vertical and the horizontal one)?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a little portion of white space between the captions and the content.

Comment: If it is thin enough, yes. Take a look at other examples all over the place where, for example, the column captions are separated from the content by `\hline\hline`.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Is there anything left which isn't solved? If the latter, please explain what's still missing/wrong. If the former, how about giving some feedback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, but also a [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) version. The requested version uses two `tabular`s that are aligned at the `[b]`ottom.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\rowlabelsep}
\newlength{\collabelsep}

\setlength{\rowlabelsep}{5pt}
\setlength{\collabelsep}{5pt}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[b]{ | c | }
  \hline
  \bfseries Row 1 \\
  \hline
  \bfseries Row 2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}%
\hspace{\rowlabelsep}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{ | c | c | }
  \hline
  \bfseries Col 1 & \bfseries Col 2 \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-.4pt+\collabelsep]
  \hline
  1 & 2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 4 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ l c c }
  \toprule
  & \bfseries Col 1 & \bfseries Col 2 \\
  \midrule
  \bfseries Row 1 & 1 & 2 \\
  \bfseries Row 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the lengths `\rowlabelsep` and `\collabelsep` to change the gaps.

Comment: Great idea the two tabulars :)

Comment: Really a good idea, but one that only works for ordinary sized contents.

Answer (score 2):

In the following I use code that I wrote for an unpublished package (unpublished meaning it is not on CTAN -- and might never be). I just copied the code and made it compatible with this MWE with the least possible effort, so it might not be an optimal implementation for the stuff you want to achieve.

I don't include a documentation of what is possible with `\MYcline` and what isn't here.

Also I personally think this doesn't look good and won't advise you to typeset a table like this!

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%% MYcline >>>
%%=============================================================================
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\int_new:N \l_MYtab_tmpa_int
\int_new:N \l_MYtab_tmpb_int
\tl_new:N \l__MYtab_cline_output_tl
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_output_single:nNnnnn% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    % #4 right skip
    % #5 start column
    % #6 end column
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__MYtab_cline_output_tl
      {
        \@multicnt#5
        \advance\@multispan\m@ne
        \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne
          \@firstofone{&\omit}
        \fi
        \@multicnt#6
        \advance\@multicnt -#5
        \advance\@multispan\@ne
        \group_begin:
          \color{#1}\rule{#3}\arrayrulewidth
        \group_end:
        \group_begin:
          \bool_if:NTF #2 { \color { #1 } } { \CT@arc@ }
          \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
        \group_end:
        \group_begin:
          \color{#1}\rule{#4}\arrayrulewidth
        \group_end:
        \cr
        \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}
      }
  }% <<<
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \MYtab_cline_output_single:nNnnnn { xNxxxx }
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_output_strip:nNnnnn% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    % #4 right skip
    % #5 start column
    % #6 end column
    \MYtab_cline_output_single:xNxxxx
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
      #2
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #3 } }
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #4 } }
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #5 } }
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #6 } }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Npn \MYtab_cline_split_columns:nNnnw #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 - #6 \q_stop% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    % #4 right skip
    % #5 start column
    % #6 end column
    \MYtab_cline_output_strip:nNnnnn { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Npn \MYtab_cline_get_columns:nNnnw #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 \q_stop% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    % #4 right skip
    % #5 columns
    %\tl_analysis_show:n { #5 }
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { #5 } { , }
      { \MYtab_cline_column_group:nNnnn { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
      {
        \tl_if_in:nnTF { #5 } { - }
          {
            \MYtab_cline_split_columns:nNnnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 } #5 \q_stop
          }
          {
            \MYtab_cline_output_strip:nNnnnn { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
            { #5 }
          }
      }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_column_group:nNnnn% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    % #4 right skip
    % #5 column group
    %\tl_analysis_show:n { #5 }
    %\tl_analysis_show:n { #6 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_MYtab_tmpb_int { \clist_count:n { #5 } }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #5 }
      {
        \int_decr:N \l_MYtab_tmpb_int
        \MYtab_cline_get_columns:nNnnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 } ##1 \q_stop
        \int_compare:nNnT \l_MYtab_tmpb_int > 0
          { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__MYtab_cline_output_tl { \omit } }
      }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_peek_column_group:nNnn% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    % #4 right skip
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_group_begin_token
      { \MYtab_cline_column_group:nNnnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 } }
      { \MYtab_cline_get_columns:nNnnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 } }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Npn \MYtab_cline_get_right_skip:nNnw #1 #2 #3 [ #4 ]% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    % #4 right skip
    %\MYtab_cline_peek_column_group:nNnn { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 }
    \MYtab_cline_get_columns:nNnnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } { #4 }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_peek_right_skip:nNn% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [%]
      { \MYtab_cline_get_right_skip:nNnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } }
      { \MYtab_cline_get_columns:nNnnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } { .5\tabcolsep } }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_peek_right:nNn% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF >
      { \MYtab_cline_peek_right_skip:nNn { #1 } #2 { #3 } }
      { \MYtab_cline_get_columns:nNnnw { #1 } #2 { #3 } { 0pt } }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Npn \MYtab_cline_get_left_skip:nNw #1 #2 [ #3 ]% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    % #3 left skip
    \MYtab_cline_peek_right:nNn { #1 } #2 { #3 }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_peek_left_skip:nN% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [%]
      { \MYtab_cline_get_left_skip:nNw { #1 } #2 }
      { \MYtab_cline_peek_right:nNn { #1 } #2 { .5\tabcolsep } }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_peek_left:nN% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF <
      { \MYtab_cline_peek_left_skip:nN { #1 } #2 }
      { \MYtab_cline_peek_right:nNn { #1 } #2 { 0pt } }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Npn \MYtab_cline_individual_color:Nw #1 [ #2 ]% >>>
  {
    % #1 if star
    % #2 fill color
    \MYtab_cline_peek_left:nN { #2 } #1
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_peek_color:nN% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    % #2 if star
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [%]
      { \MYtab_cline_individual_color:Nw #2 }
      { \MYtab_cline_peek_left:nN { #1 } #2 }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_peek_star:n% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF *
      { \MYtab_cline_peek_color:nN { #1 } \c_true_bool }
      { \MYtab_cline_peek_color:nN { #1 } \c_false_bool }
  }% <<<
\cs_new:Nn \MYtab_cline_arg_parser:nn% >>>
  {
    % #1 fill color
    \int_set:Nn \l_MYtab_tmpa_int { \clist_count:n { #2 } }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
      {
        \int_decr:N \l_MYtab_tmpa_int
        \MYtab_cline_peek_star:n { #1 } ##1 \q_stop
        \int_compare:nNnT \l_MYtab_tmpa_int > 0
          { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__MYtab_cline_output_tl { \omit } }
      }
  }% <<<
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \clineReveal { }% >>>
  {
    \noalign { \vskip \arrayrulewidth }
  }% <<<
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \MYcline { }% >>>
  {
    \omit
    \MYtab@cline
  }% <<<
\NewDocumentCommand \MYtab@cline { O{white} m }% >>>
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__MYtab_cline_output_tl
    \MYtab_cline_arg_parser:nn { #1 } { #2 }
    \l__MYtab_cline_output_tl
    \clineReveal
  }% <<<
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%==========================================================================<<<

\newcommand\MyLine
  {%
    \MYcline{>[\dimexpr\doublerulesep+\arrayrulewidth]1,<[-\arrayrulewidth]2-3}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l||l|l|}
  \MYcline{<[-\arrayrulewidth]2-3}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& Col 1 & Col 2\\
  \MYcline{<[-\arrayrulewidth]2-3}
  \noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}%
  \MyLine
  Row 1 & 1 & 2 \\
  \MyLine
  Row 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \MyLine
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have created an example with Libre Office.

Answer (score 2):

Dirty trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5em}}
\newcommand{\mystr}{\rule{0pt}{3ex}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|C|@{}p{5pt}@{}|C|C|}
  \cline{3-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} && \mystr\textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2}\\
  \cline{3-4}
  \noalign{\vskip5pt}
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  \mystr\textbf{Row 1} && 1 & 2 \\
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  \mystr\textbf{Row 2} && 3 & 4\\
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Skillmon pointed out, there is a small gap at the lower left vertices of the "Col 1" cell and the " 3 " cell, with a `tikz matrix` you can avoid it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={text width=5em, draw, minimum height=4ex, text centered},
    row 1/.style={nodes={font=\bfseries}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={font=\bfseries}}
    ]{
    &[5pt] Col 1 & Col 2\\[5pt]
    Row 1 & 1 & 2\\
    Row 2 & 3 & 4\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the `\multicolumn` only in the first row and change table definition?

Comment: @Skillmon I tried but I didn't manage to separate the horizontal line

Comment: I just tried and it does work if you use `|C|@{}p{5pt}@{}|C|C|` as your preamble. Then you can use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in the first row to suppress the vertical rules for the first column. The rest doesn't need `\multicolumn` then (using `\noalign{\vskip5pt}` for the vertical gap). But you get small gaps at the lower left vertices of the "Col 1" cell and the " 3 " cell (and I don't know how to fix this without some code, e.g. with what I did in my answer).

Comment: @Skillmon Modified as you indicated, thanks!